# DOMDocument::loadXML(): Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding

Tags: php, xml, encoding

Im generating a XML file from database that is formated to utf-8 and creating a XML file, however for a some specific case it is not converting properly and displaying me this message :

DOMDocument::loadXML(): Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0x96 0x20 0x50 0x61 in Entity, line: 1

I have already tried all possible online solutions, going from iconv , trying to do regex but none of these are solving the problem. The mb_encoding returns it is ASCII , which is supposedly UTF-8, even checking the file itself its utf-8.

This is my file start which loads the file path from the database which is the variable $xml_file, all inputs from database are being decoded using utf8_decode.

```
<?php
$content = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($xml_file));
//$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($content);
//$myXMLString = file_put_contents($xml_file, iconv('WINDOWS-1251', 'UTF-8', file_get_contents($xml_file)));
$xml_doc = new DomDocument();
$xml_doc->formatOutput = true;
$xml_doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml_doc->loadXML($content);
?>
```

This is only happening with some items because other generate correctly, however i can not find any particular difference between them neither a permanent fix for this.

HOW I FIXED :

$content = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $content);

Comment: Can you share the original file?

Comment: @miken32 Posted it just now bud, looking foward to have your help

Comment: I meant in your code you've got `file_get_contents($xml_file)`. What does that look like, before you've done anything else with it?

Comment: @miken32  Check the file that creates the xml in the original post, it first creates a XML file , then i save that XML path in database and i pull it with file_get_contents to add articles to it.

Comment: Ok, was confused by "generated XML" in the original question. So the block of XML you've got above is from the original file stored on disk? That doesn't look like valid UTF-8 to begin with. Is that whitespace at the beginning of the file as well?

Comment: @miken32 Yes but was when i copied that it got the whitespace.  However when you can its encoding in any file editor it ill say its utf8 but seems like some parameters are not passing

Comment: I fixed it ! Added this before loading the XML $content = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $content);

Comment: You may have 'fixed' it but do note that the byte sequence `0x96 0x20` is definitely **not** valid UTF-8. The high order bit of the first byte indicates it is a multi-byte character, but the next bit is not a `1`..

Comment: @user268396 what encoding is it then?

Comment: I don't know, it is probably mojibake. But I do know it is not UTF-8 because it does not obey the rules of UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this converting it again to UTF-8:

```
$content = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $content);
```